# Auto resize view objects for different screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

usually I take out storyboard in my projects and and put my view objects like buttons, labels and etc by writing in view like bellow :

```
 class welcomeScreen : UIView {

let btn : UIButton!
override func viewLoad(){
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
//define frame for Button
btn = UIButton(frame : self.screenAutoLayoutCalc(19.32,42.44,64.73, 15.73))
btn.setTitle ("submit",.Normal)
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
//add to view
self.addSubview(btn)
}

//calculate object x, y, width and height based by bounds size
func screenAutoLayoutCalc(x:CGFloat,y:CGFloat,w:CGFloat,h:CGFloat) {

let screenSize : CGRect = self.bounds
let returnCG : CGRect = CGRect()
returnCG.origin.x = round((screenSize.width * x)/100)
returnCG.origin.y = round((screenSize.height * x)/100)
returnCG.size.width = round((screenSize.width * w)/100)
returnCG.size.height = round((screenSize.height * h)/100)
return returnCG


}
 }
```

I would like to know, is there another way to make responsive design in iOS (swift) programming?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can achieve adaptivity of visual elements in your app. You will need to learn about [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)

> People generally want to use their favorite apps on all their devices and in any orientation. In iOS 8 and later, you use size classes and Auto Layout to help you meet this expectation by defining how the layout of screens, view controllers, and views should adapt when the display environment changes.

and NSLayoutConstraints.

> A constraint defines a relationship between two user interface objects that must be satisfied by the constraint-based layout system.

I would recommend learning the basic of size classes and constraints using storyboard and then slowly working your way to write code instead of clicking and dragging inside storyboard.

I would recommend you to read through this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) for the introduction.